# Best flash player for webcam streaming via Red5 Media Server?

Tags: flash, streaming, media-player, jwplayer

Each profile page on my web application should have flash player that will play a live stream from users webcam. I have installed Red5 Server, enabled and tested RTMP. Streaming from webcam works, and now I need to integrate this into the user profile pages.

How to do that? What player should I use, please suggest from experience. There are so many solutions, but I need a best (free) one.

I want a player that can play live webcam streaming when particular user is online. When he is offline, there should be no possibility to play.
There should be HD format, and there should be no ads or something similar, I saw that thousands of websites use this but cannot figure out which one!

Comment: JW Player works with Red5 in Flash. I've tested it before and it works fine.